# Setup a pubcenter account as European citizen te receive money from advertising

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8, ads

I've been on Microsoft Pubcenter for a while and at the moment i've reached more dan +€50 income from advertising. On the pubcenter website they say you need to be a citizen of the US, but I know it is possible some way. Does anyone know a good tutorial for setting up a payment account as EU citizen?

EDIT: The reason I thought it wasn't working was because i got an error. But when I clicked OK, everything was set up correctly, so there was not a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to figure out whether your account is American or European. If it's European, you shouldn't have a problem setting a payment method. If it's American, then you'll have to create an European account, contact the support, and hope they'll agree to migrate your fund. They did it one or two years ago, when European residents couldn't register and bypassed by using American accounts, I don't know if they'll do it again.